# Prove the following bound for the following sequence

Tags: analysis

Define a sequence by $a_1= \frac13$ and $a_{n+1}=a_n(1-a_n)$ for $n=1,2,\dots$.

How can I show that $a_n\geq \frac{1}{3n}$?

I proceed by induction:

Im stuck in the following:

We have that $0\leq a_n \leq \frac 13$. Then I have that $a_{n+1}\geq \frac 29$. But I need to get $a_{n+1}\geq \frac{1}{3(n+1)}$.

Any ideas or another way to do it, I will appreciate?

Comment: If $a_n\le \frac{1}{3}$ then $-a_n\ge -\frac{1}{3}$ so $1- a_n\ge \frac{2}{3}$ but that is, as you observe, "going the wrong way".  Instead use that fact that $0\le a_n$ so that $1- a_n\le 1$.

Answer (score 4):

I may be missing a much easier proof here, but I believe you can prove

$$\frac{1-\sqrt{(3n-1)/(3n+3)}}{2} \leq a_n \leq \frac{1+\sqrt{(3n-1)/(3n+3)}}{2}.\;\;\; (*)$$

The trick here is to realize that if the above is true, then it is true that

$$\left(a_n - \frac{1-\sqrt{(3n-1)/(3n+3)}}{2} \right)\left(a_n - \frac{1+\sqrt{(3n-1)/(3n+3)}}{2} \right) \leq 0.$$

Upon rearranging, this is equivalent to

$$a_n(1-a_n) \geq \frac{1}{3(n+1)}.$$

That is, proving $(*)$ for $a_n$ implies that $a_{n+1}\geq \frac{1}{3(n+1)}$. We use induction to prove $(*)$.

The base case $n=1$ is true. In the inductive step, you need to prove the estimate

$$a_{n+1}\leq\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{(3n-1)/(3n+3)}}{2}\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{3n}\right)\leq \frac{1+\sqrt{(3n+2)/(3n+6)}}{2}.$$

Note, we also use here that $a_n\geq \frac{1}{3n}$, which is true by the inductive hypothesis $(*)$ on $a_{n-1}$.

This inequality follows from the fact that the function

$$f(x) := \frac{1+\sqrt{(3x+2)/(3x+6)}}{2}-\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{(3x-1)/(3x+3)}}{2}\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{3x}\right)$$

is monotone, satisfies $f(1)>0$ and $\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x) = 0$.

To conclude we establish the estimate

$$a_{n+1} \geq \left(\frac{1-\sqrt{(3n-1)/(3n+3)}}{2}\right)\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{(3n-1)/(3n+3)}}{2}\right) \geq \left(\frac{1-\sqrt{(3n+2)/(3n+6)}}{2}\right).$$

Again, here we show the second inequality by constructing an associated function (as above) and showing that it is monotone decreasing to 0.

I admit that I have only checked these associated functions graphically, but I believe this proof method should be sufficient. I would be very interested in a more elementary proof.

Comment: "$\frac{3n-1}{3n(n+1)} \leq \frac{1}{n+2}$" Sure about that?

Comment: You are correct; I made a typo in my calculations! The answer I have given is false; I will work to edit it. Thank you for drawing attention to the error.

Comment: You are welcome. (Unrelated: the votes on the site are as surprising as ever.)

Comment: Elementary: for every $n$, $a_{n+1}=f(a_n)$ with $f(x)=x(1-x)$. The function $f$ is increasing on $(0,\frac12)$ and $a_n$ is in $(0,\frac12)$ for every $n$ hence the desired result follows if it holds at $n=1$ and if $f(1/(3n))\geqslant1/(3(n+1))$ for every $n$. This holds if $(3n-1)/(9n^2)\geqslant1/(3(n+1))$, which is equivalent to $(3n-1)(n+1)\geqslant3n^2$, which is true, qed.